# Nodejs Payload too large(Http 413) on base64string

Tags: node.js, express, base64

I uploaded an Image of size 413kb and whenever I convert to base64string and send it over to nodejs server, I got a `payload too large` error with `413` error code.
Does it mean that the size of base64string is not dependent on the size of image converted. Articles found only stated that base64string is *1.3333 time bigger than actual size*, but how is `413kb` a `payload too large`.

**Already did this but didn't solve the issue.**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "9091990mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "9091990mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:90000}));

app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
}));
```

Comment: first of all, are you the owner of the server? you can easily check the limit if you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I noticed I had the following lines of code:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

So, what I did was comment the lines (or remove it) and it worked just fine.